# Long text in x-axis is cut in bar graphs ng2-charts

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js, ng2-charts

I've tried the bar graph in the documentation and it works fine responsively. But when I try to enter long text with grid layouts, the ticks of the x-axis is getting cut as in the following. I'm using ng2-charts here. I've tried the callback function but doesn't seem to work.

```
xAxes: [{
    stacked: false,

    scaleLabel: {
        labelString: 'Month'
    },
    ticks: {
        stepSize: 1,
        autoSkip: false,
        mirror: true,
        "callback": function (tick, index) {
            tick = tick.replace(' and ', ' & ');
            if (tick.length > 20) {

                tick = tick.split(" ").join("\n");
            } else {
                tick;
            }
            return tick;
        },
    }
}]
```

[image]

Comment: try using css margin...

Comment: It didn't help. The canvas is already loaded so I guess there's nothing much to be done with css.

Comment: you can format the tick..https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/254

Comment: Above code is the way I tried formatting by adding a new line instead of spaces. Seems like the ticks are just taking the new line as a space.

Answer (score 0):

Having faced this issue in my project, I realized ng2-charts doesn't provide you anyway that you can display long ticks. So I had to move to google-charts.

[NPM documentation for ng2-google-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-google-charts)

If you are having a hard time configuring  refer this [article](http://anthonygiretti.com/2017/10/12/using-google-charts-in-angular-4-project-part-2/) - **Using Google Charts in Angular 4 project**

If it's not scroll-able in mobile view, use css such as

```
<div class="google-chart-row">
  <pie-chart [data]="question.googleChartData" [elementId]="question.questionId"></pie-chart>
</div>

.google-chart-row{
  display: block;
  width: 100 %;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
```